# Multiple STS authentication servers using Thinktecture

Tags: authentication, thinktecture-ident-server

I am going to preface this by saying I am a novice in this field. Our system has a large number of users, some of whom, log in using SAML authentication, others use the forms authentication on the home page, and some use a custom built Single Sign On solution. This happens because different clients prefer different modes of authentication.
We are looking to streamline authentication so that it is not a function of the web application, and we are therefore going by the claims model. One of the infrastructure options to build the STS is the Thinktecture Identity server.

My question is this:
- Is is possible to have multiple STS for the same web app, and if so, where does the switching happen? I.e if user1 uses SAML, how is this user's credentials sent to that specific STS?

Also, is Thinktecture the right infrastructure to be building something like this, or should I look at something else?